# remove "Edit columns" during the edit mode for a SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, settings

How can I remove "Edit columns" during the edit mode for specific users in a SharePoint Online List as shown below?
Based on the permission level, there is no associated setting.
[image]

The current settings of the permission level which this user group is associated to:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “Edit columns” button is visible to everyone who has access to this list form (even for *View Only*), but users who have no permission to edit list forms will get Access Denied when trying to use this feature.

It is currently not supported to remove this button using OOB settings.

I would suggest you submit this idea via the SharePoint UserVoice forum: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration?category_id=144150

Comment: thx and also posted it here https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/41820637-remove-edit-button-from-editing-a-record-in-a-shar